# Scrapy csv output "randomly" missing fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, scrapy

My scrapy crawler correctly reads all fields as the debug output shows:

```
2017-01-29 02:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.willhaben.at/iad/immobilien/mietwohnungen/niederoesterreich/krems-an-der-donau/altbauwohnung-wg-geeignet-donaublick-189058451/>
{'Heizung': 'Gasheizung', 'whCode': '189058451', 'Teilmöbliert / Möbliert': True, 'Wohnfläche': '105', 'Objekttyp': 'Zimmer/WG', 'Preis': 1050.0, 'Miete (inkl. MWSt)': 890.0, 'Stockwerk(e)': '2', 'Böden': 'Laminat', 'Bautyp': 'Altbau', 'Zustand': 'Sehr gut/gut', 'Einbauküche': True, 'Zimmer': 3.0, 'Miete (exkl. MWSt)': 810.0, 'Befristung': 'nein', 'Verfügbar': 'ab sofort', 'zipcode': 3500, 'Gesamtbelastung': 1150.0}
```

but when I output the csv using the command line option

```
scrapy crawl mietwohnungen -o mietwohnungen.csv --logfile=mietwohnungen.log
```

some of the fields are missing, as the corresponding line from the output file shows:

```
Keller,whCode,Garten,Zimmer,Terrasse,Wohnfläche,Parkplatz,Objekttyp,Befristung,zipcode,Preis
,189058451,,3.0,,105,,Zimmer/WG,nein,3500,1050.0
```

The fields missing in the example are: `Heizung, Teilmöbliert / Möbliert, Miete (inkl. MWSt), Stockwerk(e), Böden, Bautyp, Zustand, Einbauküche, Miete (exkl. MWSt), Verfügbar, Gesamtbelastung`

This happens with a few values that I scrape. One thing to note is that not every page contains the same fields, hence I generate the field names depending on the page. I create a dict containing all the fields present and `yield` that in the end. This works as the DEBUG output shows. However, some csv columns don't seem to be printed.

As you can see some columns are blank because other pages obviously have these fields (in the example 'Keller').

The scraper works if I use a smaller list to scrape (e.g. refine my initial search selection while keeping some of the problematic pages in the results):

```
Heizung,Zimmer,Bautyp,Gesamtbelastung,Einbauküche,Miete (exkl. MWSt),Zustand,Miete (inkl. MWSt),zipcode,Teilmöbliert / Möbliert,Objekttyp,Stockwerk(e),Böden,Befristung,Wohnfläche,whCode,Preis,Verfügbar
Gasheizung,3.0,Altbau,1150.0,True,810.0,Sehr gut/gut,890.0,3500,True,Zimmer/WG,2,Laminat,nein,105,189058451,1050.0,ab sofort
```

I have already changed to python3 to avoid any unicode string problems.

Is this a bug? This also seems to only affect the csv output, if I output to xml all fields are printed.

I don't understand why it does not work with the full list. Is the only solution really to write a csv exporter manually?

Comment: For instance I can't see `Keller` column in debug output and, in opposite, can't see `Teilmöbliert / Möbliert` as CSV column. Looks like you messed up columns and fields, do you use `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` setting in your project?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the words columns and fields interchangeably, because they are supposed to be the same. However, some fields are not output as columns. As I explained, the reason why there is a `Keller` column in the csv but not in the debug output for this specific entry is that other entries have a Keller field, but this particular one doesn't. (I'm only showing one of many csv rows in this post.)

Comment: Also, I'm not using `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` since I don't know the names of the fields in advance (they are generated depending on what is present on the pages) and I don't care about the order they are printed in.

The question as to WHY there is no column named `Teilmöbliert / Möbliert` in the csv output is exactly my question ;-) It obviously works with smaller lists using the same code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you yielding scraped results as dict, CSV columns will be populated from the keys of first yielded dict:

```
def _write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export(self, item):
    if self.include_headers_line:
        if not self.fields_to_export:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                # for dicts try using fields of the first item
                self.fields_to_export = list(item.keys())
            else:
                # use fields declared in Item
                self.fields_to_export = list(item.fields.keys())
        row = list(self._build_row(self.fields_to_export))
        self.csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

So you should either define and populate `Item` with all the fields defined explicitly, or write custom `CSVItemExporter`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on [mizhgun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41921397/5446749):

I created an item pipeline that writes the csv output. When iterating through every item it stores the set of unique keys and writes the csv file in the end. Remember removing the `-o` option when calling `scrapy crawl` and adding the pipeline to `settings.py`:

**pipelines.py**

```
import csv
import logging

class CsvWriterPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('mietwohnungen.csv', 'w', newline='')
        #if python < 3 use
        #self.file = open('mietwohnungen.csv', 'wb')
        self.items = []
        self.colnames = []

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(self.file, fieldnames = self.colnames)#, delimiter=',')
        logging.info("HEADER: " + str(self.colnames))
        csvWriter.writeheader()
        for item in self.items:
            csvWriter.writerow(item)
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # add the new fields
        for f in item.keys():
            if f not in self.colnames:
                self.colnames.append(f)

        # add the item itself to the list
        self.items.append(item)
        return item
```

**settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'willhaben.pipelines.CsvWriterPipeline': 300,
}
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41917108/2) to the question [Scrapy csv output "randomly" missing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917108/scrapy-csv-output-randomly-missing-fields) by the OP [MoRe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521347/more) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>