# Python scrapy - yield initial items and items from callback to csv

Tags: python-2.7, export-to-csv, scrapy

So I've managed to write a spider that extracts the download links of "Videos" and "English Transcripts" from this [site](http://saltanat.org/videos.php?topic=SheikhBahauddin) . Looking at the cmd window i can see that all the correct information has been scraped.

The issue I am having is that the output csv file only contains the "Video" links and not the "English Transcripts" links (even though you can see that it's been scraped in the cmd window).

I've tried a few suggestions from other posts but none of them seem to work.

The following picture is how I'd like the output to look like:
[CSV Output Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68AM6.png)

this is my current spider code:

```
import scrapy

class SuhbaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "suhba2"
    start_urls = ["http://saltanat.org/videos.php?topic=SheikhBahauddin&gopage={numb}".format(numb=numb)
        for numb in range(1,3)]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield{
            "video" : response.xpath("//span[@class='download make-cursor']/a/@href").extract(),
        }
        fullvideoid = response.xpath("//span[@class='media-info make-cursor']/@onclick").extract()

        for videoid in fullvideoid:
            url = ("http://saltanat.org/ajax_transcription.php?vid=" + videoid[21:-2])
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_transcript)

    def parse_transcript(self, response):
        yield{
            "transcript" : response.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'english')]/@href").extract(),
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy csv output "randomly" missing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917108/scrapy-csv-output-randomly-missing-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are yielding two different kinds of items - one containing just `video` attribute and one containing just `transcript` attribute. You have to yield one kind of item composed of both attributes. For that, you have to create item in `parse` and pass it to second level request using `meta`. Then, in the `parse_transcript`, you take it from `meta`, fill additional data and finally yield the item. The general pattern is described in [Scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments).

The second thing is that you extract all videos at once using `extract()` method. This yields a list where it's hard afterwards to link each individual element with corresponding transcript. Better approach is to loop over each individual video element in the HTML and yield item for each video.

Applied to your example:

```
import scrapy

class SuhbaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "suhba2"
    start_urls = ["http://saltanat.org/videos.php?topic=SheikhBahauddin&gopage={numb}".format(numb=numb) for numb in range(1,3)]

    def parse(self, response):
        for video in response.xpath("//tr[@class='video-doclet-row']"):
            item = dict()
            item["video"] = video.xpath(".//span[@class='download make-cursor']/a/@href").extract_first()

            videoid = video.xpath(".//span[@class='media-info make-cursor']/@onclick").extract_first()
            url = "http://saltanat.org/ajax_transcription.php?vid=" + videoid[21:-2]
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_transcript)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_transcript(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item["transcript"] = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'english')]/@href").extract_first()
        yield item
```

Comment: That would be suspicious since there would be requests to `ajax_transcription.php` for videos without transcriptions. It's important that your Spider behaves exactly as the site does. That said, you must check for transcription existence through selectors and only make requests to the ones that do have them.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend to add `X-Requested-With` header with `XMLHttpRequest`. Same reason.

Comment: I tried to provide an example applying main ideas, not provide ready-to-run code. Checking site specifics is up to the OP.

Comment: @TomášLinhart Thanks a million for the explanation and solution, it works perfectly!

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. thanks for the suggestions, I hadn't thought of those, will definitely add them in